# Sitecore powershell script to delete selected items from results

Tags: powershell-extensions

Below is the Sitecore Powershell Script to delete selected items from Powershell script result -

```
foreach($Item in $selectedData)
{
    if($Item -ne $null)
    {
        $Item | Remove-Item

    }
}
```

But the deleted items still appear in ListView results.
 How to update the list view results?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get the item from either from master or web database and after that need to remove it from the all data list and then need to update the list view  -

```
foreach($selectedItem in $selectedData) {
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $selectedItem.ID


$item | Remove-Item
    $allData.Remove($selectedItem)
}

$allData | Update-ListView
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me.