# Sitecore Powershell Script to Delete All Items in Results

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to delete all the items present in the list view on the click of the "delete all" action button.

[image]
I am running the script -

```
foreach($selectedItem in $allData) {    
   $item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $selectedItem.ID
   $item | Remove-Item
   $allData.Remove($selectedItem) 
}
```

But it deletes only the first item in the list. Maybe it is throwing some error in `$allData.Remove($selectedItem)`. 
When I try to execute it in ISE with test data in `$allData`, it throws below error:

```
Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
```

Please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: why do you want to remove item from $allData? are you doing anything with it?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat Based on previous question at https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/22542/605, it seems that he wants to update the listview

Comment: @Surya I went on with Mahendra Shekhawat's comment and didn't update $allData. Instead, showed a popup that all the items are deleted and closed the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop if you want to update collection within the loop

**Example** -

```
for($index = $allData.Count-1; $index -ge 0; $index--) {
   $item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $allData[$index].ID
   $item | Remove-Item
   $allData.RemoveAt($index) 
}
```

If `$allData` is a collection of items then below script is enough to remove items and update `$allData` collection -

```
for($index = $allData.Count-1; $index -ge 0; $index--) {
   $allData[$index] | Remove-Item
   $allData.RemoveAt($index) 
}
```