# How to delete specific saved Sitecore Forms entries using SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-forms

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.1 and using the default Save Data submit action on my form:

[image: save data submit action]

There are many garbage entries due to test and bot submissions, and there isn't a way to delete any of the entries.

[Sitecore 9.3 appears to offer deletion functionality](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/delete-form-entries.html), although it is limited; only supporting deletion of all entries and entries for a specified date range.

We have been using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to allow users to view the form entries within Sitecore itself, thanks to these [Forms Data Viewer SPE scripts](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/F/Forms_Data_Viewer.aspx). The scripts ultimately leverage the [Show-ListView](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/show-listview) SPE function to display and export the data like so:

[image: Sitecore Forms entries list view]

Now I just need to make the final leap and allow individual entries to be deleted. Any ideas about how I can approach this? It's not clear to me because the data listed in the table doesn't correspond to items, so it's not as simple as doing a [simple delete via SPE](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22542/sitecore-powershell-script-to-delete-selected-items-from-results).

I've done some digging to see what `Sitecore.Experience.Forms.Data` provides in terms of functionality. Here's a decompilation:

```
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data
{
    public interface IFormDataProvider
    {
        void CreateEntry(FormEntry entry);

        void DeleteEntries(Guid formId);

        IReadOnlyCollection<FormEntry> GetEntries(Guid formId, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like it provides an interface for deleting specific entries. It's all or nothing (at least on Sitecore version 9.0.1.). The question now becomes how can I see what's in `DeleteEntries` and how can I extend the `IFormDataProvider` to add the necessary functionality? From there I should be able to write the necessary PowerShell script for the list view action.

Another option seems to be to [run SQL directly on the form entry table](https://sitecoresafari.wordpress.com/2019/05/21/clear-sitecore-9-forms-data/). Then it becomes a question of how to plug and play that with SPE via a custom action within the list view.

Comment: If you want to see what DeleteEntries exactly does, you'll need to compile the relevant DLL. Use DotPeek or similar.

Comment: @Kasaku it doesn't seem possible to decompile the code; only the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Without customization, it is not possible to do this on your version of Sitecore Forms.

If using `Sitecore.ExperienceForms` version 4 which ships with SC 9.3 (and perhaps some earlier versions), the following approach may work:

```bash
$formId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" # your form Item ID
$serviceType = [Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IFormDataProvider]
$service = [Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator]::ServiceProvider.GetService($serviceType) -as $serviceType

# Use highly specific date times to single out individual entries
$startDate = [datetime]::Parse("2022-01-01 00:00:00")
$endDate = [datetime]::Parse("2022-01-01 00:01:00")

$service.DeleteEntries($formId, $startDate, $endDate)
```